# Docker Bench for Security for image on Google Cloud

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an image in Container Registry and deployed to App Engine flex.

How do I use Docker Bench for Security to check my containers security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Docker Bench for the images that are uploaded in the Google Cloud Container Registry. 
You can do it locally with the following command:

```
docker run -it --net host --pid host --userns host --cap-add audit_control \
-e DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=$DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST \
-v /etc:/etc:ro \
-v /usr/bin/docker-containerd:/usr/bin/docker-containerd:ro \
-v /usr/bin/docker-runc:/usr/bin/docker-runc:ro \
-v /usr/lib/systemd:/usr/lib/systemd:ro \
-v /var/lib:/var/lib:ro \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
--label docker_bench_security \
docker/docker-bench-security
```

For more information on Docker Bench usage you can check [this](https://github.com/docker/docker-bench-security)

I think you should also be able to replicate this process with Cloud Build. You can check the documentation to see how to use it.

[Cloud Build quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-build)

[Cloud Build config reference](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config)